# A good graphics API for simple Java animation?

Tags: java, swing, animation

As part of a team based project I'm looking into some potential 2D frameworks/API that our system could use to animate an array (e.g. swaps, deletions) So far, I've come across the Timing-Framework. I've implemented a basic animation in this framework (simple x to y movement), but it's library & examples appears to be quite complex.

Does anyone know of any simpler frameworks/API that can be incorporated into Eclipse or any other suitable IDE for constructing this simple animation? I've looked at others but most still seem rather complex at face-value.

Comment: java.util.Timer + java.util.JComponent.paintComponent?

Comment: To be honest, you can use the TimingFramework or [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home). Any good animation framework is going to have a level of complexity that your going to have to overcome. I use the TimingFramework in production using a simple wrapper API to help deal with these complexities

Answer (score -1):

java.awt.Robot class is used to generate native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed. The primary purpose of Robot is to facilitate automated testing of Java platform implementations.

For [demo](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t84094.html) check this site or [demo in java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/0980__Robot.htm)

Comment: And how does that help with animation within the Graphics2D API?

Comment: How do you plan to interact with Graphics2D in an automated way ?

Comment: It's not a question of automation, it's a question of animation, I can't see how this helps